# Double quote to single quote R

Tags: r, list, double-quotes

I want to call a list with 26 elements, one by one, and by its name,ie:

```
list$'91469_1'
```

I've tried paste0 and other functions in stringr package:

```
name<-paste0("'",as.character(d$bicho[i]),"'")
> name
[1] "'91469_1'"

> sQuote(d$bicho[i])
[1] "‘91469_1’"
```

There's any solution for my problem?

Comment: you should probably use double-bracket indexing: `list[["'91469_1'"]]` -- but your question isn't entirely clear.  What is the result of `head(names(list))` ?

Comment: You can also use backticks: `list(\`'91469_1'\`=1:3, \`'12345_x!'\`=4:6)`

Comment: Yeah you're right @Ben Bolker, I completely forgot about double brackets, sorry about that..

Answer (score 2):

First off, there are usually no single or double quotes in the names of list elements. They are displayed on the console with double quotes and that is the action of the print method for names and character vectors. If you want to change how they are displayed, then you need to rewrite the print methods.

If you have taken actions with `paste` or `paste0` that have added single quotes to a character vector element that you wish to use as an index into a list, vector or dataframe, then you need to use a backslash or backticks, but in your first example there are no single-quotes (or backticks) in the name that is being used. The single-quotes there are acting to signify to the interpreter that the token formed by `91469-1` is interpreted as an atomic character rather than as a name to be looked up (or even worse a value to be calculated).

```
mylist <- list()
mylist$'91469_1' <- 42

> mylist
$`91469_1`
[1] 42
> nchar(names(mylist))
[1] 7
```

The only reason the print method puts backticks around that element name is that names are not supposed to start with decimals. Notince no backticks with a "proper" R name that starts with a alpha:

```
> mylist$'m91469_1' <- 46
> mylist
$`91469_1`
[1] 42

$m91469_1
[1] 46
```